# Is there an "app" tag in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Are there any tags in Django templates to show the current app (e.g. blog)?

So I can do something like

```
<nav>
  <li {% if request.app == "index" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>Home</li>
  <li {% if request.app == "blog" %}class="selected"{% endif %}>Blog</li>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can always send the app name in the context, or write a template context processor that would inject the app name in the context

Comment: But then I'd have to do it in every view - breaking the DRY principle of Django.

Comment: You'd be better off looking at the current URL to decide whether or not the page is 'active', instead of trying to check apps

Comment: @jdborg That is what template context processors are for

Comment: There's no such thing as "current app", only "current view" which happens to be in a Django app.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using:

```
{% if request.path|startswith:"/blog/" %}class="selected"{% endif %}
```

Which has meant adding the following template tag:

```
@register.filter
def startswith(value, arg):
    """Usage, {% if value|starts_with:"arg" %}"""
    return value.startswith(arg)
```